# How do you prove that the identity function is a bijection?

Tags: functions

At least in $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z},$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: can you think of an inverse for the identity?

Comment: The identity function on _any_ set is a bijection. Just prove separately that it satisfies the definitions of "injective" and "surjective" -- it is _extremely_ straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You prove that it is injective and surjective. Let's say $id: A\to A$ is the identity function on $A$.

1. *Prove that it is surjective:* Take $a\in A$. Can you find some $x\in A$ such that $id(x)=a$?
2. *Prove it is injective:* Take any two $a,b\in A$ and assume that $id(a)=id(b)$. Can you now prove that $a=b$?

Comment: How do you prove that $a = b$? What I mean is, do you have to 'prove' something at all? Isn't that the proof already? Same with the surjection proof.

Comment: @TheBosco Well, yes, you have to prove something. You have to prove that if $id(a)=id(b)$, then $a=b$. And you have to prove that for each $a\in A$, you can find some $x$ such that $id(x)=a$.

Comment: @TheBosco The proof is trivial, sure, but you still have to be able to write it down. Just saying "isn't *that* the proof" won't cut it, especially since I have **no** idea what you are refering to when you say *that*.